# Could not find Alljoyn AboutConfOnbServer.apk(Onboarding Server) source code

Tags: alljoyn

I find onboarding client source code in Onboarding SDK samples but I could not find the server sample.Where can I find AboutConfOnbServer.apk(Onboarding Server) source code. Both onboarder and onboardee is running android.

Comment: if the answer below responds to your question, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

https://git.allseenalliance.org/cgit/services/base.git/tree/simulators/android?id=v16.04

Please note that this is for v16.04